# Connecting python socketio_client to nodejs server facing 400 error code

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, socket.io

I tried to connect python client to node.js server, and experience HTTP 400 errors.

node.js server code:

```
var socket = require('socket.io');
var express = require('express')
  , http = require('http');

var app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080);

var server = http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});

var io = socket.listen(server);
io.sockets.on('connection', function () {
 console.log('hello world im a socket');
});
```

python client code:

```
from socketIO_client import SocketIO

def on_response(*args):
    print 'on_response', args

import logging;
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

socketIO = SocketIO('localhost', 8080)
socketIO.on('news', on_response)

socketIO.wait(seconds=1)
```

when i run client.py after starting the server getting the following error:

```
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET /socket.io/1/ HTTP/1.1" 400 None
```

If I create a javascript client, then it works well. Could someone help me resolve this issue please?

Comment: `socketIO_client` hasn't been updated in 8 months and probably isn't compatible with the current version of SocketIO.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ..Is there any other module by which i can connect python client to nodejs server and send messages to server..

Comment: There are at least 3 other WebSocket modules that I know of. [Tornado](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/stable/websocket.html) has a good implementation.

Comment: There is now a bounty to get this updated:
https://www.bountysource.com/issues/2413561-socket-io-v-1-0-is-out
Hopefully the client will be updated soon. Contribute if this is important to you...